# Как подключиться к базе данных pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

через pythonanywhere работает но локально нет

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='hayk1',password='HvU7B@P9w73Nf4H',host='hayk1.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',database='hayk1$my_hl',)
cursor=conn.cursor()


cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM abc")
rows=cursor.fetchall()
for i in rows:
    print(i)


conn.commit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hayk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 200, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hayk1.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (10060)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hayk/Desktop/Pycharm/pycharm/baza_danni/baza danni_pythonaniwhere.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='hayk1',password='HvU7B@P9w73Nf4H',host='hayk1.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',database='hayk1$my_hl',)
  File "C:\Users\Hayk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 176, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hayk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hayk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 781, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Hayk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 203, in _open_connection
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hayk1.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (10060)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка MySQL `10060` обычно говорит о том, что *удаленное соединение* не сработало.

Если в качестве имени хоста указать `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` или ничего не указывать, то на UNIX системах соединение будет строиться через `UNIX socket file`. Если же указать любое другое имя host'а, то для соединения будет использоваться `TCP/IP` протокол.

Причин возникновения ошибки `10060` на стороне MySQL сервера может быть несколько:

- по указанном порту (по умолчанию это порт 3306) никто не слушает. Например сервис MySQL привязан только к `localhost` / `127.0.0.1`. В этом случае надо правильно сконфигурировать параметр MySQL сервиса `bind-address` и рестартовать сервис.
- IP interface указанный в параметре `--host` - не поднят или не работает правильно.

Чтобы проверить слушает ли какой-либо MySQL сервис на порту 3306 (порт используемый MySQL по умолчанию) и привязанный к указанному в параметре `--host` IP, можно воспользоваться командой `telnet`:

```
telnet mysql_hostname_or_ip_address 3306
```

если данная команда отработала без ошибок, значит указанные выше причины проблемы можно исключить.

Comment: Может лучше `ss -lnpt | grep 3306` чтобы проверить?

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо за совет - не знал этой команды. А `ss` умеет проверять порт удаленно?

Comment: Нет,  только локальные.